# WEB API post from uri/ Query string in post

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, http-verbs

i have a model

```
    public partial class TalentVendorShots
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string One { get; set; }
        public string Two { get; set; }
        public string Three { get; set; }
        public string Four { get; set; }
        public string Five { get; set; }
        public string Six { get; set; }
        public string Seven { get; set; }
        public string Eight { get; set; }
        public string Nine { get; set; }
        public string Ten { get; set; }
    }
```

and basic controllers

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TalentVendorShotsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly champagneDatabase _context;

        public TalentVendorShotsController(champagneDatabase context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/TalentVendorShots
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TalentVendorShots>>> GetTalentVendorShots()
        {
            return await _context.TalentVendorShots.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/TalentVendorShots/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TalentVendorShots>> GetTalentVendorShots(int id)
        {
            var talentVendorShots = await _context.TalentVendorShots.FindAsync(id);

            if (talentVendorShots == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return talentVendorShots;
        }

        // PUT: api/TalentVendorShots/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutTalentVendorShots(int id, TalentVendorShots talentVendorShots)
        {
            if (id != talentVendorShots.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(talentVendorShots).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!TalentVendorShotsExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/TalentVendorShots
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TalentVendorShots>> PostTalentVendorShots(TalentVendorShots talentVendorShots)
        {
            _context.TalentVendorShots.Add(talentVendorShots);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetTalentVendorShots", new { id = talentVendorShots.Id }, talentVendorShots);
        }

        // DELETE: api/TalentVendorShots/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TalentVendorShots>> DeleteTalentVendorShots(int id)
        {
            var talentVendorShots = await _context.TalentVendorShots.FindAsync(id);
            if (talentVendorShots == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.TalentVendorShots.Remove(talentVendorShots);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return talentVendorShots;
        }

        private bool TalentVendorShotsExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.TalentVendorShots.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

all of this works fine. i get information from the database fine. now i want to make a post to the table via uri. no body.for example
/api/TalentVendorShots/id=1,email=testemail should create a new record with id of 1 and email of testemail. how can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The basic rule is, You should use POST if the action is not **idempotent**. Though you can pass the query parameters and no body to POST. But It would not make sense in this scenario. Basically query parameters are used to get/filter information.

Similar way many Web API testing tools like ARC, Swagger, and PostMan (chrome extension does not allow, but standalone application allows) does not allow to send body with the GET request. Though you can send the body in GET requests.